# Regular Expression for string that end with exactly 1 '.csv' pattern

Tags: regex

How can a regular expression be written to include strings of the form

```
/foo/bar.csv
```

But exclude strings of the form

```
/foo/bar.csv.csv
```

In other words, **what regular expression matches exactly 1 instance of a string suffix pattern?**

Note: the `"/foo/bar"` component is inconsequential, e.g. it could be any generic string that doesn't contain the `".csv"` pattern.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a multi-line file regex will be:

```
(^[\w\/]+\.csv)$
```

You can check it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/UUUxB0/1)
Also you can add anything you like into first group `[\w\/]` except any matches for dot.

Comment: This has been driving me nuts ... why doesn't `m = re.search(r'csv(?!\.csv)', s)` work?